# how do I build a dynamic SQL statement which varies depending on number of elements in listbox?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, listbox

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ParamsListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {


        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                dualSearchVar = ParamsListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                valVar = TextFieldListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                valVar = valVar.Replace(" ", empty2);
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("dualSearchVar", TypeCode.String, dualSearchVar));
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("valVar", TypeCode.String, valVar));
                SqlAddon = SqlAddon + "AND @valVar LIKE '%@dualSearchVar%'";
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                dualSearchVar1 = ParamsListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("dualSearchVar1", TypeCode.String, dualSearchVar1));
                valVar1 = TextFieldListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                valVar1 = valVar1.Replace(" ", empty2);
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("valVar1", TypeCode.String, valVar));
                SqlAddon = SqlAddon + "AND @valVar1 LIKE '%@dualSearchVar%'";
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                dualSearchVar2 = ParamsListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                valVar2 = TextFieldListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                valVar2 = valVar2.Replace(" ", empty2);
                SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("valVar2", TypeCode.String, valVar2));
                SqlAddon = SqlAddon + "AND @valVar2 LIKE'%@dualSearchVar%'";
            }
        }


    }
        if (dateType == "DateFiled") 
        {

            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField1", TypeCode.String, DateField1));
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_AddedFields2 WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN CAST(@DateField1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@DateField2 AS DATE)" + SqlAddon;
            SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

So I'm doing a search in my database based on up to 3 parameters in a listbox, then adding that to the end of a SQL statement with a date range, one addon per added parameter.  I have to declare the parameters separately in the if-then I think because they are in the same for-loop together.  I had this working at one time, but am stumped now.  I've run a test query against the database and it should be pulling in two records, Tom Cruise and Tom Hanks when I give the date parameters and the string 'tom'.  I'm not getting an error, just no results.  (FYI - SqlAddon starts out as an empty string.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_AddedFields2 
WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN '05/17/2017' AND '06/19/2017' AND PersonReporting LIKE '%tom%';
```

This is the query I'm trying to duplicate. When I pause int the debugger it looks like this -

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_AddedFields2 
WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN CAST(@DateField1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@DateField2 AS DATE)AND @valVar LIKE '%@dualSearchVar%'
```

Comment: When you pause the code in the debugger right before the databind, what does the SelectCommand contain?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_AddedFields2 WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN '05/17/2017' AND '06/19/2017' AND PersonReporting LIKE '%tom%';  This is the query I'm trying to duplicate.  When I pause int the debugger it looks like this - SELECT * FROM tbl_AddedFields2 WHERE DateFiled BETWEEN CAST(@DateField1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@DateField2 AS DATE)AND @valVar LIKE '%@dualSearchVar%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your data, but looks like it should be

```
            dualSearchVar = ParamsListBox.Items[i].ToString();
            valVar = TextFieldListBox.Items[i].ToString();
            valVar = valVar.Replace(" ", empty2);
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("dualSearchVar", TypeCode.String, "%"+dualSearchVar+"%"));
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("valVar", TypeCode.String, valVar));
            SqlAddon = SqlAddon + " AND @valVar LIKE @dualSearchVar";
```

If you are trying to pass a column name as @valVar , it's definitely not the way to do it. Drop @valVar prm, and after you checked and sanitized user input,

```
SqlAddon = SqlAddon + " AND " + valVar + " LIKE @dualSearchVar";
```

Comment: It doesn't work to add the % symbol in the SelectParameters.Add statement.  I'm building a SQL query to test the SQL database.  The information isn't in the c# code.  It is only within the database.  And I need it to work should I change the database (SqlDataSource).

Comment: If you are trying to pass a column name as  @valVar , it's definitely not the way to do it. Drop @valVar prm, and after you checked and sanitizes  user input, `SqlAddon = SqlAddon + " AND " + valVar + " LIKE @dualSearchVar";`

Comment: Yes, that worked Serg!  Thank you!.  Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.  So column names are not parameters, just the values within the database.  Is that correct?

Comment: SqlAddon = SqlAddon + " AND " + valVar1 + " LIKE '%@dualSearchVar%'"

Comment: This is the exact syntax that ended up working so Serg's answer was only partially correct.  I still needed the wildcards around dualSearchVar.